# Que signifie la réplique culte : « Vous voulez un whisky ? - Oh juste un doigt. - Vous ne voulez pas un whisky d'abord ? » ?

Tags: humour, dialogues

Une très célèbre [scène de La Cité de la Peur (1994)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FlJsZTpcXs) où Odile Deray et
le commissaire Patrick Bialès passent la soirée ensemble a pour dialogue :

> Commissaire Bialès : « Vous voulez un whisky ? »
>
> Odile Deray : « Oh, juste un doigt. »
>
> Commissaire Bialès : « Vous ne voulez pas un whisky d'abord ? »

Pendant de nombreuses années je me suis posé la question de la signification de cette réplique. Je sais bien sûr qu'elle est très drôle pour beaucoup de français, en témoignent mes collègues, amis, famille etc. Je sais aussi qu'elle a une très forte connotation sexuelle, mais je ne parviens néanmoins pas à la comprendre entièrement.

Ce que je sais est qu' « un doigt » est une quantité de whisky, ce que je ne saisis pas est la dernière réplique du commissaire, qu'a-t-il pu comprendre d'autre que la quantité de whisky ? Forcément, il a dû comprendre quelque chose de sexuel mais je ne parviens pas à saisir quoi et donc pourquoi ceci a du sens pour lui en réponse à sa première question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La réplique a été indubitablement écrite pour être comprise par le plus grand nombre comme étant du registre sexuel. Le commissaire n'a pas compris qu'Odile souhaitait un doigt de whisky, mais a cru qu'elle désirait une « visite intime » du doigt de ce dernier.

Elle est antérieure au film « La cité de la peur », étant apparue pour la première fois deux ans plus tôt, dans un sketch joué en direct par les mêmes comédiens (Gérard Darmon et Chantal Lauby) dans « [les Nuls, l'émission](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Nuls,_l%27%C3%A9mission) », au cours d'une parodie de roman photo justement nommée « [Roman Photo](https://youtu.be/RaY-zen33hg) ».

Les romans photos de l'époque étaient « à l'eau de rose », en gros décalage avec la pensée de Sandra lue en voix off « J'ai la culotte qui palpite », le fameux « Oh, juste un doigt » puis « Tu n'as pas trop chaud, tu ne veux pas enlever ta robe » qui ne laissent aucun doute sur la compréhension qu'il faut avoir de la scène.

[L'Express](https://www.lexpress.fr/culture/cinema/video-la-cite-de-la-peur-en-dix-moments-mythiques_1937378.html)

> S'ensuit ce très subtil sous-entendu: "Vous ne voulez pas un whisky d'abord?"

[Wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/La_Cit%C3%A9_de_la_peur_(film,_1994))

> Le soir du quatrième jour, Odile dîne avec le commissaire Bialès, une tension sexuelle s'installe vite entre eux et la soirée se poursuit à l'appartement du commissaire. Cela donne l'occasion à une des répliques les plus connues du film : Bialès : -« Vous voulez un whisky », Odile : -« Oh, juste un doigt », Bialès : « Vous voulez pas un whisky d'abord ? ». [...] À l'appartement de Bialès, Odile et le commissaire viennent de faire l'amour lorsqu'Odile découvre accidentellement le costume du tueur dans la garde-robe de Bialès.

Answer (score 1):

La réplique peut être également comprise sans allusion sexuelle et comme un trait de "nonsense". On peut simplement rire du fait que le commissaire Bialès interprète la réponse "juste un doigt" littéralement,  c'est à dire comme "je voudrais juste manger un doigt", tout comme dans d'autres passages du film où les personnages prennent des expressions au pied de la lettre ("prenez la place du mort"). De manière générale,  les Nuls étaient plus des adeptes d'humour absurde à la Monty Python que d'allusions sexuelles.

Comment: J'en tombe des nues... Quelque chose n'aurait pas passé la frontière ? Le quiproquo graveleux a sa place dans l'humour absurde des Nuls.

Comment: J'étais tout aussi étonné de voir votre réponse... 20 ans à ressortir ces répliques avec mes potes lors de soirées arrosées... et j'aurais manqué une allusion sexuelle ? J'avoue que je me remets profondément en question. Je n'avais jamais vu le sketch original, où l'allusion sexuelle est plus claire. J'avais pris cela plus au premier degré comme les autres expressions comprises au pied de la lettre dans le film ("prenez la place du mort", "j'attends ma soeur"). J'adapte ma réponse en conséquence.

Comment: "juste un doigt" ne peut avoir que deux sens : (1) un doigt de whisky (2) un doigt dans un endroit que rigoureusement ma mère m'a défendu de nommer ici. S'il était question de "manger un doigt" au lieu de prendre un verre, elle devrait dire "non, [pas un whisky, mais] juste un doigt"

Answer (score -3):

Dans le contexte stricte de l'extrait on peut comprendre la répartie à cette réplique courante comme ceci.
Ça ne va pas plus loin que l'humour habituel en ce qui concerne la sobriété: nous sommes tous plus ou moins imbus de sobriété, tenus à la sobriété par les exigences du cadre social, mais nous avons tous la notion que la pleine jouissance des nourritures terrestres n'est pas nécessairement dans la sobriété d'un acsète. Aller plus loin, en particulier dans la veine sexuelle, c'est du mauvais gout, à mon avis. Ce qui est insinué, donc,  c'est que de trop grand soucis de sobriété vont à l'encontre de la réalité et qu'il est toujours temps de se rappeler de la sobriété ensuite, cela selon des normes raisonnables — il ne s'agit que d'un whiskey.

Comment: Et vice et versaaaaaa (par allusion à d'autres humoristes français de la même époque ).

Comment: LPH: avez-vous vraiment vu le film? On parle des Nuls, pas de Schopenhauer..

Comment: @Greg C'est plus dans la veine superficielle, et ce « vice » n'est pas franc ! Ça amuse alors que la réplique instruit.

Comment: @Greg Peu m'importe le film, tout ce qu'il faut pour la compréhension se trouve dans l'extrait, il me semble.

Comment: Regardez le film en entier... vous verrez que le ton général n'est pas du tout celui que vous lui prêtez.  C'est un film d'humour absurde. Les acteurs jouent cette scène dans un registre franchement "pince-sans-rire".

Comment: @Greg Ah oui, je comprends, je vais modifier ma réponse légèrement, parce ce que je trouve intéressant c'est mon interprétation.